# How to use JSON.parse in this example

Tags: javascript, json

I want to use  `JSON.parse` to convert json to an object. I don't know where I should put this code,  in the `function makeChart()` ? If so, how exactly?

So far I have got:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
(obj.tot1);
(obj.tot2);
(obj.tot3);
```

Where & how do I use this in this example:

```
    function makeChart() {

    var tot1v = 
    var tot2v = 
    var tot3v = 

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("colChartContainer", {
        theme: "theme2",
        title: {
            text: "Coin Toss Results"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "column",
            dataPoints: [{
                label: "tot3",
                y: tot1v
            }, {
                label: "tot2",
                y: tot2v
            },{
               label: "tot3",
                y: tot3v                   
            }]
        }]
    });

    chart.render();
}
```

I have modified this http://jsfiddle.net/jx9sJ/5/ . I'm using canvasjs.com .

Comment: And why not declare and set the json out of CanvasJS.Chart parse, etc... etc and pass in CanvasJS.Chart like "var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("colChartContainer", json);"

Comment: @vzamanillo Please can you explain in more detail? This example is the very first thing I've coded, ever. Thank-you.

Comment: Where are you getting the response from and what's its format? Can you create a fiddle with your own data? Judging by what you provided, it should be `tot1v = obj.tot1` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want, not really that bigger change.

```
function makeChart(response) {

var obj = JSON.parse(response);

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("colChartContainer", {
    theme: "theme2",
    title: {
        text: "Coin Toss Results"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [{
            label: "tot3",
            y: obj.tot1
        }, {
            label: "tot2",
            y: obj.tot2
        },{
           label: "tot3",
            y: obj.tot3                   
        }]
    }]
});

chart.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer seems to work:

`tot1v = obj.tot1` .

Not sure why yet.